# Enter blank value in try statements

Tags: python

I am making a blackjack game for school and for this part, the user can choose their bet. It can be 0 to quit, press enter to keep the previous bet, or type a new bet. I got the enter 0 part, but I think my ValueError is blocking the user from entering a blank value. I apologize for the messy code. Is there another except statement I could add in to allow some mistakes, or do i need to restructure the entire loop?

```
import random
import sys

def main():

  restart = True

  bank_balance = 1000
  player_name = input("Please enter your name: ")
  while (restart):

    print (f"Welcome {player_name}, your bank balance is ${bank_balance} ")

    correct = False
    user_bet=0
    bet = input_bet(user_bet, bank_balance)

    if (user_bet == 0):
      print('Quiting the game')
      break


    win_lose = play_hand(player_name, bet)
    bank_balance+=win_lose

    print(f'Your bank balance: ${bank_balance}')

    play=bet



def input_bet(bet, money):
  correct = False
  while not correct:
    try:
      enough_money = False
      while not enough_money:
        bet=int(input("Bet? (0 to quit, press 'Enter' to stay at $25) ")) 
        if (bet > money):
          print('not enough money')
        elif (bet == 0):
          return 0

        elif (bet <= money):
          print(f'Betting ${bet}')
          enough_money=True
          return bet

      correct = True

    except ValueError:
      print('Please enter a number')



def play_hand(name, bet):




  player= []
  dealer= []

  play_again = True

  dealer.append(random.randint(1, 11))

  player.extend([random.randint(1, 11), random.randint(1, 11)])

  print ('The dealer received card of value', *dealer)
  print(name, 'received cards of value', player[0], 'and', player[-1])
  print(f'Dealer total is {sum(dealer)}')
  print(f"{name}'s total is {sum(player)}", '\n')

  stay = False
  bust = False

  while (sum(player) <= 21 and stay == False and play_again == True):
    hors= input(f"Type 'h' to hit and 's' to stay ")
    if (hors == 'h'):
      new_card= random.randint(1, 11)
      player.append(new_card)
      print(f'{name} pulled a {new_card}')

      print(f'Dealer total is {sum(dealer)}')
      print(f"{name}'s cards are", *player)
      print(f"{name}'s total is {sum(player)}", '\n') 

    elif (hors == 's'):
      stay=True
      print('stay')


  if (sum(player) > 21 ):
    bust = True
    print('You busted!')
    return -bet



  while (stay == True and sum(dealer) < 17 and bust == False and play_again == True):
    dealer.append(random.randint(1, 11))
    print('The dealers cards are', *dealer)
    print('The dealers total is', sum(dealer), '\n')

  if (sum(dealer) <= 21 and sum(dealer) > sum(player)):
    print("The dealer wins!")
    return -bet


  elif (sum(player) <= 21 and sum(player) > sum(dealer)):
    print("You win!")
    return bet


  if (sum(dealer) > 21):
    print ('You win! The dealer busted!')
    return bet

  if (sum(dealer) == sum(player)):
    print('Its a Tie! ')
    return 0


main()
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the stack trace that happens when the `ValueError` occurs?

Answer (score 0):

The immediate issue is that `int("")` raises a `ValueError`, rather than returning `0` like `int()` does. The solution is to check the return value of `input` before you attempt to produce an `int`.

```
def input_bet(money):
    while True:
        response = input("Bet? (0 to quite, press 'Enter' to stay at $25) ")
        if bet == "0":
            return 0

        if bet == "":
            bet = "25"
        try:
            bet = int(bet)
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a number")
            continue

        if bet > money:
            print("Not enough money")
            continue

        return bet
```

The only parameter `input_bet` needs is the player's total amount, to prevent betting more than is available. No initial bet is needed.